# How to populate dynamically created imageview through urls asyncronously...In Android

Tags: image, android-imageview, android

I am using horizontal pager

https://github.com/ysamlan/horizontalpager/blob/master/src/com/github/ysamlan/horizontalpager/HorizontalPager.java

to make dynamic views,and making dynamic images in it....

And using fedor imageloader to pupulate imageviews from urls...
https://github.com/thest1/LazyList/blob/master/src/com/fedorvlasov/lazylist/ImageLoader.java

but i am getting that annoying stid image....
here is my code...

Any help or suggestion will be highly appropriated

Thanx in advance

```
public class testing extends Activity {

private HorizontalPager mPager;
 ImageView[] image;

 String url = "http://icons-search.com/img/icons-land/IconsLandVistaStyleEmoticonsDemo.zip/IconsLandVistaStyleEmoticonsDemo-PNG-256x256-Cool.png-256x256.png";

 @Override
 public void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.testing);
  ImageLoader imageLoader = new ImageLoader(this);
  mPager = (HorizontalPager) findViewById(R.id.horizontal_pager);

  image = new ImageView[2];
  for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {

   image[i] = new ImageView(getApplicationContext());
   image[i].setImageResource(R.drawable.logo_background);
   RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams90 = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
     225, 250);
   layoutParams90.leftMargin = 25;
   image[i].setLayoutParams(layoutParams90);
   mPager.addView(image[i]);

  }

  for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
   imageLoader.DisplayImage(url, image[i]);
  }
 }

}
```

Comment: Universal Image Loader is the other library (not Fedor Vlasov's LazyList) so delete this tag from your question.

Comment: @DroidGeek: Can post What error or warning you are getting.?

Comment: @Surej I am not getting any error or warnings..I am just getting that grey stub image...(which shown when Image is loading a/c to fedor)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create ImageView try to pass your Activity instead of Application context. So replace this

```
image[i] = new ImageView(getApplicationContext());
```

with this

```
image[i] = new ImageView(this);
```

Comment: Thank You @Fedor for your Great support :)

Comment: BTW fedor please,let m know where I was doing mistake :(

Answer (score 0):

Please check whether you added external storage and internet permission in your android manifest file?

Comment: @Droid: Please Check Your Image Url as per fedor said.

Answer (score 0):

You need to localize the problem first. Probably there's something wrong with the url you use - try another one. Probably something related to Pager - try without pages, just put all images into LinearLayout. What else may be a problem - just find some clue. Does it work if you just put a single ImageView to the screen?

Comment: ,thank you very much for your reply.... :)
I put that URL as a sample,I am using urls that I getting from Jason,and I tested those urls in logs,they are all well and passing in imagloader correctly...
It works well when I use your imageloader with imageviews that are set on XML...

BUt my need as same as above,I need to generate views dynamically as I mentioned in my above code....

Comment: If you create ImageView dynamically but put them to LinearLayout not to Pager what happens?

Comment: ok,thats what I didnt cheked,I will check it soon and post the result...thank you again for you consistent support :)

Comment: I did the same what you old me that create ImageView dynamically but put them to LinearLayout,but its same issue,its not showing the image from url,its showing that grey stub image.... :(

Comment: Have to looked into LogCat. Probably there are some errors. Probably you have just forgotten to specify PERMISSION_INTERNET. You should just debug and understand what's going on. There's no magic, nobody but you can figure out the problem.

Comment: I did all these things...Given all needed permissions,I debugged it but it all goes in vein....I am trying my level best to figure out where the actual issue is... :(